# How to send mail from users Gmail with Oauth in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm currently working on website project. It's intended to be used by business owners to send invoices to their customers. Each owner is a django user model instance and have an organization model associated to them. Now I don't know how to ask permission from owner to give me access to him account and used these credentials to send invoices to customers. I'm working with django and drf. A minimalist HTML CSS and JavaScript are used for front. I had already done mail sending with Gmail but only for desktop app and I needed to save app credentials to filesystem. Does exist anyway to do it with web app ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example] please describe the issues you are having with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sending mail from someone's gmail is not going to work. You're going to need a domain which you'll need to connect with a mailing service such as mailjet or mailgun.